# How to check if a file exists using expo-file-system?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have already done the following:

Here is the path of my file that I want to check if it already exists in my cell phone directory.:

> file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-192.168.0.66-CPEX-Force/2021-09-05.doc

And here's my code, where `const { exists } = response` always returns `true`, even if the file doesn't exist.

```
await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri).then(async (response) => {
  const { exists } = response;


  if (exists) {
    // If exists not continue
  } else {
    // continue...
  }

});
```

How can I check if the file exists created with the same name within this path?

Answer (score 1):

**you should use `await` OR `then`**

**getInfoAsync** is an async function - as the name implies. It returns a **Promise** so you either need to use await or then:

```
let tmp = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri);
//your code will await for 'tmp' result
```

OR

```
FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri).then(tmp => {
    //this code will be executed when 'tmp' results
});
```